# cstore_fdw extension: FATAL: could not access file "‘cstore_fdw’": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, columnstore, postgresql-extensions

I've installed the cstore_fdw extension in PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on OS X, and it looks as though there was no error in the process (`/usr/local/pgsql/bin/` is incorrect path, but files were copied where they should be, as `pg_config` is symlinked in the `$PATH`):

```
XXX:cstore_fdw kjedrzejewski$ sudo PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/:$PATH make install
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/lib'
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755  cstore_fdw.so '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/lib/cstore_fdw.so'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./cstore_fdw.control '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./cstore_fdw--1.3.sql ./cstore_fdw--1.2--1.3.sql ./cstore_fdw--1.1--1.2.sql ./cstore_fdw--1.0--1.1.sql  '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/share/postgresql/extension/'
XXX:cstore_fdw kjedrzejewski$
```

However, when I try to start Postgres, the extension cannot be loaded:

```
XXX:cstore_fdw kjedrzejewski$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
server starting
XXX:cstore_fdw kjedrzejewski$ FATAL:  could not access file "‘cstore_fdw’": No such file or directory
```

Has anyone got any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Hey, could you also show us the line in your postgresql.conf with the `shared_preload_libraries` configuration setting? It's weird to see those double quotes in the error message!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the quotes around your config value are smart quotes? They need to be normal quotes:

```
shared_preload_libraries='cstore_fdw'
```